# Read and write from/to a binary file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io, binary

My knowledge of matlab is merely on a need to know basis, so this is probably an elementary question. Nevertheless here it comes:

I have got a file containing data (16-bit integers) stored in binary format. How do I read it into a vector /an array in matlab? How do I write this data to a file in matlab? Is there any smart tweak to increase the performance speed when reading/writing a huge amount of data (gigabytes)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As [Bill the Lizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205735/read-and-write-fromto-a-binary-file-in-matlab#205819) wrote you can use fread to load the data into a vector.  I just want to expand a little on his answer.

#### Reading Data

```
>> fid=fopen('data.bin','rb') % opens the file for reading
>> A = fread(fid, count, 'int16') % reads _count_ elements and stores them in A.
```

The commands *fopen* and *fread* default to Little-endian[1] encoding for the integers.  If your file is Big-endian encoded you will need to change the *fread* to

```
>> A = fread(fid, count, 'int16', 'ieee-be');
```

Also, if you want to read the whole file set

```
>> count=inf;
```

and if you want to read the data into matrix with *n* columns use

```
>> count=[n inf];
```

#### Writing Data

As for witting the data to a file.  The command, *fwrite*, in [Bill's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205735/read-and-write-fromto-a-binary-file-in-matlab#205819) answer will write to a binary file.  If you want to write the data to a text file you can use *dlmwrite*

```
>> dlmwrite('data.csv',A,',');
```

#### References

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

#### Update

1. The machine format (IE, *ieee-be*,
   *ieee-le*, *vaxd* etc.) of the binary data can be specified in either the
   *fopen* or the *fread* commands in Matlab.  Details of the supported
   machine format can be found in
   Matlab's documentation of *fopen*.
2. [Scott French's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4928/scott-french) comment to [Bill's
   answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205735/read-and-write-fromto-a-binary-file-in-matlab#205819)
   suggests reading the data into an
   int16 variable.  To do this use

   ```
   >> A = int16(fread(fid,count,precision,machineFormat));
   ```

   where *count* is the size/shape of
   the data to be read, *precision* is
   the data format, and *machineformat*
   is the encoding of each byte.
3. See commands *fseek* to move around the file.  For example,

   ```
   >> fseek(fid,0,'bof');
   ```

   will rewind the file to the beginning where *bof* stands for *beginning of file*.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you know how many values you have stored in the file, you can do something like this to read the data into an array.

```
fid = fopen('data.bin','rb')
A = fread(fid, count, 'int16')
```

To write data to a file do this:

```
fid = fopen('data.bin','w')
count = fwrite(fid, A, 'int16')
```

The fwrite function returns the number of *elements* (not bytes) written to the file.

As far as performance tuning goes, you can read data in chunks to only use as much as you need to process.  This is the same in any language, and there's no way to speed it up that's specific to Matlab.

Comment: Note that the 'int16' argument to fread will read data as int16's but blow each of them up to double precision, which can be a significant performance hit. Depending on what you are doing with the data you might want to use '*int16', which reads int16's into variables of type int16.

Answer (score 0):

I usually hate seeing links in a response, but this looks pretty close:

http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1400/1403.html

As to the second part of performance tuning, it's been 6 years since I've used Matlab, so I don't know.

HTH