# How to convert a binary file to a matlab file?

Tags: matlab

I need to convert a  binary file to a matlab file, I try to do that by using:

```
>> movefile('traces.bin','traces.mat')
ans =  1
>> text= load ('traces.mat')
error: load: failed to read matrix from file 'traces.mat'
>> movefile('traces.mat','traces.bin')
```

But this function doesn't give me any results.

I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: What does traces.bin contain? A matrix? If so, in which format? A .bin can contain pretty much anything, you need to know its format to read it. For sure, you cannot simply use `load`.

Comment: Yes, it contains a matrix, I also use importdata, but i have the same error,

Comment: I'm surprised that you are expecting `importdata` (or `load`) to work. How should it know the format of your binary file?

Comment: I don't think that changing the file extension with [`movefile`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movefile.html) is going to work. Rather have a look at [`fread`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html) to read data from a binary file and then use [`save`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) to save it as a `.mat` file. I suggest reading [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/205735/3599179).

Comment: @Cebri, Thank you very much, that works very well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that changing the file extension from `.bin` to `.mat` with [`movefile`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movefile.html) is going to work. Instead use [`fread`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html) to read data from the binary file and then use [`save`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) to save it as a `.mat` file.

I suggest reading the question [Read and write from/to a binary file in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/205735/3599179) for more details on how to read data from binary files.